# sending serialized object in single file in R

Tags: r, serialization, connection

I am struggling to send serialized object in a single file over the connection in R.

Here's my code

```
# Serializing model to make it a text field in TD Aster
# mod is a glm model
model_char <- paste(serialize(mod, NULL, ascii=FALSE,refhook = NULL),collapse="")
# Write model as output
output <- cbind(101, "MM Response Model", "2015-07-28", model_char)
###########
write.table(output, file=stdout(), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE,
           quote=FALSE, sep="\t", na="", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
###########`
```

If I remove collapse statement from paste function separate rows are created in `write.table` otherwise no object is created

```
101    MM Response Model    2015-07-28    27
101    MM Response Model    2015-07-28    3f
101    MM Response Model    2015-07-28    f6
101    MM Response Model    2015-07-28    e8
101    MM Response Model    2015-07-28    92
```

Answer (score 0):

`cbind` returns a data frame only if at least one of its arguments is already a data frame. In this case, they aren't, so `cbind` returns a matrix. The type of that matrix is character, since you passed it at least one character vector. To create a data frame, use the `data.frame` constructor function:

```
data.frame(101, "MM Response Model", "2015-07-28", model_char)
```

I'm assuming Aster knows what to do with the string of hex digits it will be receiving....